# Inheriting relative css styles

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have the second image in the following example also have the styles using something similar to the CSS "all:inherit" property?

HTML

```
<div class="outer-div">
  <img href="example.url">//first image
  <div>
    <img href="example.url">//second image
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer-div > img {
  height:100px;
}
```

Comment: Why not just `.outer-div img` if you want to target both? Or `.outer-div > img > div > img` to target just the inner img?

Comment: I could, but I'm trying to use some libraries that already have a lot of styles defined and was hoping I could skip a lot of editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply don't use the ">" in your css.

`.outer-div img {
}`

">" = Children

" " = All decedents

Comment: This would have the effect I like but I'm trying to bypass editing a lot of css already in place. I was hoping I could give the image a certain property to inherit something it would otherwise have if it were in the parent div.

Comment: In that case can you apply "outer-div" to both divs?

Comment: So apply "outer-div" to both divs and then undo any changes that the "outer-div" class does to the inner div?

As for inheriting all properties by default, I'm unaware of anything that would do that. That's the entire purpose for the difference between the " " vs ">"; to satisfy that need.

Comment: I would like to as well, but the "parent-div" class also has a lot of styles defined.  Maybe if I could ignore those easily, that could work.